# WebDav HttpRequest Message for COPY. Is it well formed?

Tags: c#, .net, http, webdav, bad-request

Passing the below httprequest message to perform a COPY of a file on a WebDavServer returns a 'Bad Request' response message. I am unable to figure out if something is missing or given wrong in the request message.

HttpRequest Message:

```
{Method: COPY, RequestUri: 'https://testaddress.de:8000/Test/TextDoc.txt',
 Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  User-Agent: WebDAVClient/1.0.0.0
  Destination: file:///C:/Users/user/TestCenter/Scan/TextDoc.txt
  Content-Type: text/xml
}}
```

And the response is:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', 
 Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Persistent-Auth: true
  Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 15:05:14 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 24
  Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE**
It has been pointed out to me that COPY works only if the destination is on the same server, not if the destination is a path in your local system. If copying a remote file to a local location, you need to use a GET request and handle writing the data to the local path with the response stream. 
Thanks to @Julian Reschke and @Brian Warshaw

Comment: What do you expect this request to do? It certainly won't copy the local file to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The "destination" header fields needs to be a URI, not a file name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've corrected and given the destination as a URI.
Destination: file:///C:/Users/user/TestCenter/Scan/TextDoc.txt

But the response is still the same.

Comment: In general, WebDAV servers will support only COPY destinations on the same server (thus it would need to be a http URI). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was under the impression that COPY supports a local destination. Thanks for pointing it out.. By giving the destination on the same server, it does work.

Comment: @August Think of it in these terms: the server has no knowledge (nor should you want it to) of your local file system. Its only path into your local machine should be you requesting something of it and it returning it for you to use at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to copy a remote file to a local location, you need to use a GET request and handle writing the data to the local path with the response stream.